# How do you register an Android Service in a Flutter Plugin

Tags: android, flutter, android-service, flutter-plugin

I am creating a card reader integration that uses and Android Service for part of the integration. The standard Android implementation includes an android service definition in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <service
        android:name="com.anywherecommerce.android.sdk.services.CardReaderConnectionService"
        android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

https://github.com/dazza5000/any-pay-android-sample/blob/4f7ca7af79f2494e3ec408b025446be6020c0aa4/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L43-L45

How do I define that in a Flutter Plugin so that the service definition will be added to the AndroidManifest of the app that uses it? Do I just include it as part of the library and leave it up to the user to register the service in their app `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to determine how to include a service definition in a Flutter plugin that would be added to the plugin consuming app.

What I had to do was add the service definition in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file of the plugin consuming app.

Comment: and then what? how do you start it really?

Comment: how would you reference plugin's file the file from the app's android manifest, when defining service in app's androidmanifest.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this with a service, but creating a skeleton manifest in the plugin's folders does seem to merge the skeleton into the app's manifest at build time.

For example, with the following skeleton, the `application` `meta-data` definition is merged fine.:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.plugin.restrictions_manager">
    <application>
        <meta-data android:name="android.content.APP_RESTRICTIONS"
                android:resource="@xml/app_restrictions" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

[Edit]
This approach does indeed work with a service declaration. And to see the merged AndroidManifest.xml, look in `my_plugin/build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk`, which can be browsed in Android Studio.

Comment: Hi @softwyer - I'm looking for a restrictions manager plugin for Flutter. Googling it leads to your post.
Where do you get it?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it at https://pub.dev/packages/managed_configurations